# react-native maps stopping build in android

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native maps in react native app, getting issue at build time runtask

**versions react-native**

```
"react": "v16.3.2",
 "react-native": "0.53",
 "react-native-maps": "^0.15.3",
```

**android configration**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"

    }
```

here is error :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle
change :

```
  compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"
```

To:

```
 provided "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  compile "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"
```